# Is there a clipboard manager on the cloud?

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, google-docs, cloud

I'm looking for a service like [Google Cloud Clipboard](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2010/02/web-clipboard-for-google-docs.html) which can be used not only from Google Docs but directly from my PC (Windows 7 SP1). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently evaluating [iClippy](http://iclippy.com/software).  For images and screen captures it is great.  The OCR for text leaves something to be desired.